# IntelliJ IDEA, how to have two projects with shared sources

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project

I have written a project (V2) and set up artifact to create product jar also.
Now I want to upgrade my source to new version (V3).
Most source of V2 remains, but some changes and modifications needed for V3.
In delphi I can define compiler directive to have single source file at same time, and define two project with each own directive definitions (V2 & V3) to produce both products.
How can I define two projects with same source?
what about two artifacts?
If I define two projects on two separated dir , debug shared sources on both will be a problem.

Comment: I don't think this problem should be solved on IDE level, it rather sounds like a mix of build management and version control.

Comment: Have a look at maven, pom.xml files, dependencies and versioning.